# Homeplug over long distance

Tags: networking, router, powerline-networking

I am trying to push Homeplug adapters over its "normal" use, in a long distance powerline. Specifically TL-PA2010 AV200 adapters. Consider I have a energy line like:

```
A---B---C- - -
```

The distance between points A and C (AC) are beyond Homeplug capacity, but between AB and BC it works fine. In everypoint I put a Homeplug adapter and a WiFi OpenWRT router. Router in point A connects to WAN and have DHCP and others are just switch/repeater/dumb AP.

My idea is to use a intermediate router and Homeplug adapter as a "signal booster", but seems I am missing something.

**The problem**: Router in point C is able to ping router B, but not router A. Router B is able to ping router A and C.
I think that is a limitation because input and output are in the same port of router B, due to nature of Homeplug mesh.

Any comment will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Very interesting idea, would you be able to use 2 powerline at point B ``` A--B-C--D``` and connect B and C with an ethernet cable and remove all routers?

Comment: I tried this, and also just one Homeplug adapter on point B, without router. C still can't ping A.

Comment: Tried Plug A-B-ROUTER-C-D ? IE - what @stresscool suggests, but with a router/switch at B ? And perhaps try A/B on one homeplug network and C/D on another (you can usually switch them using some sort of config utility)

Comment: AFAIK, HomePlug [AV] _does not_ create a mesh – it works strictly in direct mode, like typical Wi-Fi. (Meanwhile, the competing G.hn standard does use a mesh with adapters automatically acting as repeaters.)

Comment: Homeplug standard support AVLN (AV logical networks). IN each AVLN should be at least one Central Coordinator (CCo) which transponding traffic if some boxes not visible for all rest boxes. See diagram https://pasteboard.co/oXowBNEiuADP.png You can see your network structure by HomePlug Monitor https://shop.ethernetovercoax.tech/index.php?route=product/product&path=64&product_id=66